# Open Graph beta: How can you tag friends in a action?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I've managed to publish an activity using the [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API). How can you tag friends in a action?

I can see you can add tags in the action dashboard, but other than that it's not specified how to tag friends.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a simplified example at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/actions/#tagging

```
Actions can be tagged with places and people by specifying the place and tags optional parameters.
```

A sample call would be a `POST` to

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/{APP_NAME}:{ACTION NAME}?
  {YOUR OTHER ACTION PARAMETERS HERE}
  &place={A PLACE ID}
  &tags={COMMA SEPARATED LIST OF UIDS}&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

That would tag the users in the action, and also tag them at a place